# Complete the square for the generating functional of the Dirac field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, path-integral, dirac-equation, partition-function

Quote Peskin page 302 the Dirac generating function was
$$Z[\bar \eta ,\eta ]=\int D\bar\psi D\psi\exp[i\int dx^4 (\bar\psi (i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu -m )\psi+\bar\eta \psi+\bar\psi \eta)]$$
could be simplified by "a shift of $\psi(x)$ to complete the square"
$$Z[\bar \eta ,\eta ]=Z_0\cdot \int D\bar\psi D\psi\exp[-\int dx^4\int dy^4 (\bar\eta(x) S_F(x-y)\eta(y))]$$

One attempted to replicate the solution by introduce the following shift
$$\psi'(x)=\psi(x)+i\int dy^4 S_F(x-y) \eta(y)$$
$$\bar\psi'(x)=\psi(x)-i\int dy^4 S_F(x-y) \bar\eta(y)$$
where the quantities was defined as
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m+i\epsilon) \psi_0(x)=\eta(x)$$
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m+i\epsilon) \bar \psi_0(x)=\bar \eta(x)$$
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m) S_F(x-y)= i\delta^{(4)}(x-y)$$
$$\bar \psi=\psi^\dagger \gamma^\mu$$
where
$$\bar \psi_0(x)=-i\int dy^4 S_F(x-y) \bar \eta(y)$$
$$\psi_0(x)=i\int dy^4 S_F(x-y)  \eta(y)$$

However, during the derivation, the following quantities needed to be true,
$$i\int dx^4  \bar\psi_0(x)(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m)\psi(x)=-i\int dx^4 \bar \eta(x) \psi(x)$$
but since the operator of $(i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m)$ was after the $\bar \psi_0$ it's hard to shift operator through the gamma matrix.
One tried to start with
$$(i\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu-m+i\epsilon) \psi_0(x)=\eta(x)$$
but it didn't work.

How to complete the square for the generating functional of the Dirac field?

Comment: eq. $\bar\psi'(x)=\psi(x)-i\int dy^4 S_F(x-y) \bar\eta(y)$ is wrong, it should read $\bar\psi'(x)=\bar\psi(x)-i\int dy^4 \bar\eta(y) S_F(x-y) $.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Might be be $\bar\psi(x)-i\int dy^4\eta(y)^\dagger S_F^\dagger (x-y) \gamma^0$ where the operation for $S_F^\dagger (x-y)\gamma^0$ was not clear. The definition of $\bar \psi_0$ turned out to be wrong because, unlike the complex scalar field, the $\bar\psi$ in the Dirac field could not be viewed as an independent components and treated separately. The convenient way in this question was to define $\psi_0(x)$ and left $\bar\psi_0(x)$ implicit where its equation of motion followed.

Comment: $\gamma^0 S^\dagger \gamma^0=S$, a somewhat well-known spinor identity (easy to check!)

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Didn't see that before. Wasn't $S_F$ supposed to be an the inverse of the operator? The $\gamma^\mu p$ in the denominator so it's not clear how $\gamma^i$ component works and the range of the convergence.

Comment: $S\sim \gamma^\mu p_\mu/p^2$ and $\gamma^0\gamma^{\mu\dagger}\gamma^0=\gamma^\mu$, this one's easier to check.